# ExpressJS returns wrong response without executing endpoint

Tags: node.js, api, express, caching

I have created API using ExpressJS which works fine, but randomly I get wrong response, though my endpoint callback even isn't being executed.

Here is my route.

```
router.get('/letter/', async function (req, res) {
  const letter = req.query.letter || 'a';
  const items = await db.FundComparison.findAll({
    where: {
      title: {
        [Op.like]: `${letter}%`
      }
    },
    order: ['title'],
    attributes: ['id', 'title', 'slug'],
    limit: +req.query.limit || 5000,
    offset: +req.query.offset || 0,
    raw: true
  });

  const count = await db.FundComparison.count({
    where: {
      title: {
        [Op.like]: `${letter}%`
      }
    }
  });

  res.json({ items, count });
});
```

Express configurations

```
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
app.disable('x-powered-by');
app.locals.ENV = env;
app.locals.ENV_DEVELOPMENT = env == 'development';

app.use(useragent.express());
app.use(swStats.getMiddleware(apiSpec));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', config.root + '/app/views');

app.set('json spaces', 3);
app.set('json replacer', null);

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', config.cors);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, GameToken, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');

    //intercepts OPTIONS method
    if ('OPTIONS' === req.method) {
        //respond with 200
        res.sendStatus(200);
    }
    else {
        //move on
        next();
    }
});

app.use(logger('dev', { stream: winstonLogger.stream }));
app.use(bodyParser.text());
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '500kb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    limit: '500kb',
    extended: true
}));

app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(compress());
app.use(express.static(config.root + '/public'));
app.use(methodOverride());

const controllers = [
    ...glob.sync(config.root + '/app/controllers/*.js'),
    ...glob.sync(config.root + '/app/controllers/*/index.js'),
];

controllers.forEach((controller) => require(controller)(app));

app.use((req, res) => {
    res.status(404).json({
        isSuccess: false,
        message: 'Not found'
    });
});

app.use((err, req, res) => {
    console.log(err);

    if (err.status && err.status != 500) { // show error message if no production
        res.status(err.status).json({ message: !app.locals.ENV_DEVELOPMENT || err.message });
    } else { // send internal error
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Intrenal Server Error' });
    }       
});
```

Here the desired response

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 1024610,
      "title": "ZCAN vs VOO",
      "slug": "ZCAN-vs-VOO"
    },
    {
      "id": 638926,
      "title": "ZIV vs SVXY",
      "slug": "ZIV-vs-SVXY"
    },
    {
      "id": 638927,
      "title": "ZIV vs XIV",
      "slug": "ZIV-vs-XIV"
    },
    {
      "id": 1021290,
      "title": "ZROZ vs EDV",
      "slug": "ZROZ-vs-EDV"
    },
    {
      "id": 638928,
      "title": "ZROZ vs TLT",
      "slug": "ZROZ-vs-TLT"
    }
  ],
  "count": 5
}
```

But sometimes I get just empty array of items

```
{
  "items": [],
  "count": 5
}
```

I have tried to disable ETag, but that doesn't helped. I can't understand the root of the problem as randomly it works fine.
Please help me to understand what can be the issue.

Comment: What callback are you saying is not executed?   I'm thinking that your middleware `cache('1 day')` looks like it may play a role in what you're asking about.  What is that?

Comment: Hi @jfriend00, I have tried without apicache as well, just edited the post to remove ambiguity

Comment: If it's not executing your route handler, but still returning the empty response, then you can look at the client network trace and perhaps see whether there's a 3xx response involved or not.  You can also track ALL your middleware that comes before this handler to see if any of that is causing the issue.

Comment: I am not sure, why it returns empty array of `items` field, but count is right?

Comment: also note that this isn't called from browser, but I have tried using various request apps

Comment: It seems somehow related to your two requests. It's very likely you sometimes pass too big value in `req.query.offset`. In that case you will get no records and `count` will be greater than 0.

Comment: I make same request with same query params